# How to capture error message into a variable?

Tags: variables, error-handling, mule

To capture error message into variable I have tried as `#[message.exception]` and `#[exception]`. None of them are working.

Please assist me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be accessed as #[exception.getMessage] or #[exception.getSummeryMessage]

Answer (score 0):

This example sets a variable to a value based on the exception content. I assume that is what you are looking for. You will need a exception strategy to access the thrown exception, but you can continue the flow below doing something with that variable.

```
<catch-exception-strategy doc:name="errorhandlingCatch_Exception_Strategy">
    <set-variable variableName="myException" value="#[exception.cause] resulted in #[exception]" doc:name="Variable" />
</catch-exception-strategy>
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure on your flow throwing error. As #[exception] contain default null value if there is no exception for the current event. Better print the #[exception] value using logger and see if it is printing exception values. Post your XML code also to debug.